# What is "Sexeteria" in Jerusalem?

Tags: futurama

Now I am watching the second episode of Futurama and Bender said on the tenth minute this:

> Yeah. You're the kind of guy
>   who visits Jerusalem... and doesn't want to see
>   the "Sexeteria."

Comment: The russian translation of this sentence sounds like: "...and does not want to go into the temples.".

Comment: Or it is a bad subtitle. Maybe, it is "... and doesn't want to see the secret area".

Comment: It sounds like a version of the word "cafeteria", but for sex. If that assumption is correct, it is another joke to show how much things have changed in the future, since Jerusalem is considered a holy religious city by many people. But I haven't seen the episode so I don't know if this is correct or not.

Comment: @BrettFromLA is most likely correct, but since I can't find any official confirmation, only the series writers can really confirm for sure. My own guess is that it means a place where people buy sex. :)

Comment: The user Shadow Wizard made a good correction, it is not "Sexiteria", but "Sexeteria". The subtitles have a mistake.

Answer (score -5):

I would guess it's a double play. They are on moon but Fry is complaining he don't see real moon but rather fake moon that is more boring than Earth.

with this - In Jerusalem there is a Church of the Holy Sepulchre, a Church over who six religions have custody. Six is SEX in Latin. This church is build on place where Jesus was crucified and buried.
So In Futurama there may be a place called "Sexiteria" that is a Theme park build around the real thing but is not a real thing.

Comment: This is a bit of a stretch to be honest. I think that its a joke around the holy city having a place called "Sexiteria" as its main attraction.